# Embedding view in another view with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, view, include

I have a news controller with a 'view' action for each news item. In the 'view' action of each news item I would like to include another view, the 'add' action of the comments controller.
Basically, I need a form on each news item's page to add comments.
I have the two views but I can't manage to link them. I tried with elements, but it seems it doesn't render the view for the add comment view.

What should I do?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

Code in element:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Comment', array('class' => 'big', 'url' => array('controller' => 'comments', 'action' => 'add', $news_id)));?>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->input('comment', array('label' => false));
?>
```

Form->end(__('Submit', true));?>

Code in view:

```
<?php echo $this->element('add_comment', array('news_id' => $news['News']['id'])); ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your Element file and how you use it in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move the code from your view into an element and then call the element all over the place.

Comment: This is what I've currently implemented but it doesn't look very "caky". Is there any other way to do this? I believe an element is unnecessary here because I use the add form just in one place...

Comment: there is only one way to put a 'view in a view' and that is with elements. what is not "caky" about it? https://github.com/infinitas/infinitas/blob/dev/core/comments/views/elements/modules/comment.ctp https://github.com/Infinitas-Plugins/blog/blob/master/views/posts/view.ctp#L39 note the paths and file types (view/element)

Comment: OK, I've done this with elements. But I still have problems with validation. Please check my other question you have responded. Thank you :)