# Cakephp - Load a view from another view in a different controller

Tags: cakephp

I've been trying for the past 2 days, how to embed a view from a different controller.

I have two tables (hotels, hotelQuotes), related to each other. The hotels table is linked with a hasmany to the hotelQuotes table, and hotelQuotes with a belongsTo hotels table. Both are linked and working, they both show their related content with no problem.

The hotelQuotes it's pretty much a form, where users fill it out, and then it sends an Email with what the user filled out. Everything is working fine up to this point.

What I want is, when I show the information about the hotel, is to also show that form, I dont want the user to go to another page to fill out the form. So I pretty much want to embed the view of hotelQuotes/Add to the hotel/view.

I doing that using elements, as recommended last night in #cakephp IRC channel, and also here in StackOverFlow at: [Embedding view in another view with CakePHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853904/embedding-view-in-another-view-with-cakephp)

The problem is that when I do that, the association between the two models gets broken. I mean, the users fill out the form, but I have nowhere to know where that form is coming from, what hotel is referring to. It just doesn't show that piece of vital information for me.

I've been reading about passing variables when using elements at: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#passing-variables-into-an-element    but I don't know how to pass a variable to a form select box. I am using CakePHP 2.5.2.

I hope I explain myself clear here, any input it would be appreciated. See picture below for more info:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcG64.jpg
Edit> I just realized that the form is not even submitting when I using elements. Why would that be?

Comment: Use a hidden input element that contains either the ID of the hotel you're adding to or whatever else if its the other view.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just figured out.

The form wasn't even submitting when calling it from elements. So I just passed the action myself like so:

> ```
> echo $this->Form->create('Hotelquote', array(
>     'action' => 'add'
> ));
> ```

And now is working.

Comment: It's a nice job.